# Encryption algorithm of gnome-keyring

Tags: encryption, algorithm, gnome-keyring

What encryption algorithm does gnome-keyring use?

I've tried looking for it on their site but it seems quite hidden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [FAQ](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/SecurityFAQ#Which_cryptographic_algorithms_are_used.3F), it uses standard-issue AES-128.

Comment: +1, I spent 15 minutes looking and didn't find the FAQ. :/

Comment: Ditto, I must have hit the site 5 different ways and still missed that

Answer (score 2):

From [the FAQ](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/SecurityFAQ#Which_cryptographic_algorithms_are_used.3F):

> **Which cryptographic algorithms are used?**
>
> SHA-256 for hashing, AES-128 for encrypting the secrets. 
>   Note that although the documented file format has MD5 for the hash algorithm,
>   the key for encrypting the keyring is not generated with MD5!

Answer (score 1):

From [looking here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/gnome/gnome-keyring.html), I can see that gnome-keyring uses [libgp11](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/libgp11-0), *"a wrapper based on GLib implementing the PKCS#11 (Cryptoki) interface."*

PKCS #11 is an abstraction layer for a generic cryptographic token, and its API defines objects such as RSA keys, X.509 Certificates, DES/Triple DES keys, and more. [ [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS11)  , [2](http://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/) ]

[This gnome-keyring thread](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-keyring-list/2011-February/msg00001.html) is fairly recent; the developers discuss the use of [HKDF (RFC 5869)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869) hashing into something usable by [AES / Rijndael](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), so it's a good bet that gnome-keyring predominantly uses AES.

Answer (score 0):

The doc's are pretty ambiguous about that, only saying it uses PKCS#11 to store it. My guess would be that it uses the default encryption for the host. (Probably DES in most cases)
[The architecture](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeKeyring/Architecture)